# Printing a polynomial

Tags: java

I am trying to print a polynomial from a given number.
I did the example below, but for something like `100` it will print `1x^2+`, when I want just `x^2`. What I'm looking for is how can I make it to not print `+` and at the same time get rid of coefficients that are `1`.

Edit: I did it, it prints perfectly. Feel free to use it.

```
private static String S_frumos(int poli) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < String.valueOf(poli).length(); i++) {
        int nr = Character.getNumericValue(S_GetCoefs(poli, i));
        if (nr != 0) {
            if (i == String.valueOf(poli).length() - 1) {
                s = s + nr;
            } else if (i == String.valueOf(poli).length() - 2) {
                if ((S_zero(poli, i + 1) == 1)) {
                    if (nr != 1) {
                        s = s + nr + "x";
                    } else {
                        s = s + "x";
                    }
                } else {
                    if (nr != 1) {
                        s = s + nr + "x" + "+";
                    } else {
                        s = s + "x" + "+";
                    }
                }
            } else if ((S_zero(poli, i + 1) == 1)) {
                if (nr != 1) { s = s + nr + "x^" + (String.valueOf(poli).length() - i - 1);}
                else  { s = s + "x^" + (String.valueOf(poli).length() - i - 1);}
            } else {
                if (nr != 1){ s = s + nr + "x^" + (String.valueOf(poli).length() - i - 1) + "+";}
                else { s = s + "x^" + (String.valueOf(poli).length() - i - 1) + "+";}
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}
private static int S_GetCoefs(int poli, int x) {
    return String.valueOf(java.lang.Math.abs(poli)).charAt(x);
}
```

Comment: I think you already know what you want done--don't print terms whose coefficient is 0 and don't print the coefficient if it's 1.  Are you having a problem figuring out how to do this?

Comment: The logical order, mostly. How to organise my conditional if's.

Comment: This isn't a good question for the StackOverflow format.  We usually prefer questions where someone has tried something and can't get it to work and doesn't know why.  I'll make this suggestion: you have duplicated code that calls `Character.getNumericValue`.  Move that up and assign it to a variable, so that it appears only once.  That should also make it easier to eliminate the unwanted coefficients and terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store something of an unknown length... then you can still use an int/double array, just gets slightly more complicated.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  // Say the size is given in a command line argument.
  int coefficientNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

  int[] poly = new int[coefficientNumber];
  for (int i = 0; i < poly.length; i++)
  {
    poly[i] = 0;
  }
  // Set the highest coeffient to 1 (if there is 3 coefficients, this is coefficient
  // of x^2, if 4 coefficients, this is coefficient of x^3
  poly[0] = 1;
  printPoly(poly);
}

// To print a polynomial of unknown length.
// If the coefficient is 0, don't print it.
private static void printPoly(int[] poly)
{
  String output = "";
  for (int index = 0; index < poly.length; index++)
  {
    if (poly[index] != 0)
    {
      // If this is the first coefficient with a value
      if (output.length() == 0)
        output = poly[index] + "x^" + (poly.length - (index + 1));
      // Else if there is already some coefficient with values printed.
      else
        output += " + " + "x^" + (poly.length - (index + 1));
    } // if
  } // for
  System.out.println(output);
} // printPoly
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, storing a polynomial in one variable isn't a great idea as if you have coefficients of more than 9 you'll get confused.
A better method imo (without making a polynomial class) is to store the polynomial in an int/double array.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  // To store the polynomial x^2, you could do the following:
  int[] poly = new int[3];
  poly[0] = 1;
  poly[1] = 0;
  poly[2] = 0;
  printPoly(poly);
}

// To print it:
private static void printPoly(int[] poly)
{
  String output = "";
  if (poly[0] != 0)
    output += poly[0] + "x^2"
  if (poly[1] != 0)
  {
    if (output.size() > 0)
      output += " + " + poly[1] + "^x";
    else
      output += poly[1] + "x";
  }
  if (poly[2] != 0)
  {
    if (output.size() > 0)
      output += " + " + poly[2];
    else
      output += poly[2];
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying for variable sizes, though. More than just X^2 ones.